# Laravel 7- Getting public twice in the URL while using asset()

Tags: laravel

While using `asset()` to load a background image in a `css stylesheet`, I am getting an URL such as this

`http://localhost/LaraTest/public/public/images/5copy.jpg`

tThe **public** appears twice. But I want the URL like this `http://localhost/LaraTest/public/images/5copy.jpg` , i.e with only one **public**

Here are a few codes

**CSS**

`background: url( '{{ asset('images/5copy.jpg') }}') no-repeat;`

**.env**

`ASSET_URL= http://localhost/LaraTest/public`

**config/app.php**

`'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL','http://localhost/LaraTest/public'),`

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not require the `public` in url even once.The url should be `http://localhost/LaraTest/images/5copy.jpg` Remove the ASSET_URL from .env and change `'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),` in config/app. Laravel docs:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

Comment: @Donkarnash Then how would I include images, css files, script files stored in the public folder?

Comment: Use `asset()` helper after removing the ASSET_URL and change in config file and see what does `asset('images/5copy.jpg')` return. If you don't have a web server configured properly then you can use the built in php server during development byt running `php artisan serve` in the terminal from the root of your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to config your server for your web base url to be in public folder.

and you have **not to include public** in your url.

if you do that you dont need to config anything for asset url. and it should be like this:

```
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
```

> You have to not include /public in any URL

/public is just a directory in your laravel project:

look at this nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.laravelproject.test
                 10.0.2.2
                 192.168.43.100;
    root /srv/www/htdocs/laravelProject/public;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

root directory is `/srv/www/htdocs/laravelProject/public`

Comment: Then how would I include images, css files, script files stored in the public folder?

Comment: you can put it into folders like `/public/images` or `/public/css` these were directories. and url to access them are 'yourdomain.test/css/mystyle.css`

Comment: In addition to what you said, I changed the config/app.php file as `    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL','http://localhost/LaraTest/'),` instead of what I was doing earlier, and it worked.

Comment: @Abilogos Is what asish did a good pratice?

Comment: actually its a bad practice, since the php files & other project files should not be served with the web server, they should be only accessible with the php itself.
having the *http root* in public, insure this.